# Finding employees that are less than 10 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find employees that are less than 10 years from the hire date but when I run the query my employees keep repeating. I do not know where I'm messing up. This is what I have tried so far. Thanks. Also I'm using MS SQL

```
SELECT CONCAT('',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) AS FullName
FROM Person.Person, HumanResources.Employee
WHERE HireDate < DATEADD(Year, -10, GETDATE()) ;
/* DATEDIFF(YEAR, HireDate, GETDATE()) < 10 */
```

Comment: Exactly what purpose is served by concatenating an empty string with FirstName? This does nothing useful. And your hire date logic seems to be backwards based on what you wrote - which might be more obvious if you included HireDate in your select list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT CONCAT('', FirstName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
FROM Person.Person p JOIN
     HumanResources.Employee e
     ON p.? = e.?
WHERE HireDate < DATEADD(Year, -10, GETDATE()) ;
```

You don't provide enough information to specify the `JOIN` conditions.  But something like:

```
ON p.personid = e.personid
```

Comment: Oh alright! It solved my problem I think. Just another question would DateDiff or DATEADD be better in this situation?

Comment: @HectorJaimes . . . Your construct with `dateadd()` is the better solution.